# top command in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, expect

I am trying to get first 5 lines of top command through expect script. Im calling this expect script from a shell script along with some other stuff.

`top | head -5` gives me below output ie without cpu stats-

> top - 09:10:58 up 46 days, 17:03, 12 users,  load average: 0.01, 0.02,
>   0.00 Tasks: 138 total,   1 running, 137 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
>
> Mem:  16432400k total,  8408096k used,  8024304k free,   609200k
>   buffers Swap:  6290736k total,        0k used,  6290736k free, 
>   6754356k cached

If I run just `top` command on that remote server I can see there is a 2-3 second delay before the CPU states line is updated, can some one please help me to get all 5 lines with updated cpu states? Below is my expect script -

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set user1 abc
set pass1 pass
set timeout 8
match_max 1000
spawn ssh -C -o stricthostkeychecking=no $user1@<ip>
expect "*?assword:*"
send  "$pass3\r"
expect "?xterm*"
send "\r"
send "top | head -5\r"
expect eof
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to run `top` in `batch mode` instead of the default `interactive mode`. In addition you need to define the number of iterations that `top` performs for getting its measurements.

```
num_iterations=3
top -b -n $num_iterations | head -5
```

If you want the output to only list the top 5 processes and skip the statistic header displayed, you can try this:

```
num_iterations=3
top -b -n $num_iterations | sed -n '8,12p'
```

Also tune the value of `num_iterations` as per your need.

Comment: Yes that is correct. You can tune the value of num_iterations as per your application need.

Comment: You mean in expect script I need to add set num_iterations 3, and send "top -b -n $num_iterations | head -5" ? If so, Im getting the same output without CPU stats, On just a taught can we some how specify wait x seconds before output is piped to head command?

Comment: Do you need output for only the top 5 processes ? I find that replacing `head -5` with `head -12` lists the top 5 processes. If you want to skip the header and grab the info only for the top 5 processes, you could do `top -b -n 3 | sed -n '8,12p'`. The sed command selects lines 8-12 in the output.

Comment: Thank You for your help Tuxdude, it dint work for me..the cpu stats dont populate no matter what I try..

Comment: try top -b -n 2. This returns cpu% in second iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
top -b -n 2 -u $(whoami) | grep -A6 -B5 PID |tail -12
```

Adjust below values as per requirement.

**grep**
  -A$after_lines_count
  -B$before_lines_count

**tail** -*$($after+$before + 1)*

tail value should be [ before lines count + after lines count + 1 (PID match line) ]

If you don't want user specific details.

```
  top -b -n 2 | grep -A6 -B5 PID |tail -12
```

Note: *Number of **top** iterations are 2 (top -n 2) i.e, it takes 6 sec to display output ( depends on delay set per iteration)*

Comment: if you need only five lines use this 
"  top -b -n 2 | grep  -B6 PID |tail -7 |head -5  "